# Docker IBM SDK-8 Image - Getting thread/memory dump

Tags: java, docker

I am using the ibmcom/ibmjava:8-sdk image. How do I get the thread dump and memory dump? I started the jvm with -Xdump option. But when I give kill -3 pid - there is no message that the dump was created.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you are issuing kill command to detached container. If thats the case, then the command "docker logs " would help to get the details.

This is how I tried it out,

**1. Launched a container(detached state):**

```
docker run --rm --detach --workdir /dockapp --volume /Users/parselva/docker-test:/dockapp ibmjava:latest java -Xdump:java:events=vmstart ThreadSleep
```

**2. Read pid of the java process within the container:**

```
docker exec 97b37120ea7b ps -eaf | grep ThreadSleep

root         1     0  0 11:03 ?        00:00:00 java -Xdump:java:events=vmstart ThreadSleep
```

**3. Issued signal to the java process:**

```
docker exec 97b37120ea7b kill -3 1
```

**4. Found the location of the generated logs file using docker logs command:**

```
docker logs 97b37120ea7b
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "user", detail "" at 2017/08/07 11:10:07 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/dockapp/javacore.20170807.111007.1.0004.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /dockapp/javacore.20170807.111007.1.0004.txt
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "user", detail "".
```